# in C Why can't change this array? like arr1=arr2;

Tags: c

Why cant arr1=arr2 in function?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func(int* arr1, int* arr2)
{
    for (int i = 0;i < 3;i++)
    {
        arr2[i] = i;
    }
    **"arr1 = arr2";**
}

int main()
{
    int arr1[3];
    int arr2[3];
    func(arr1, arr2);
    for (int i = 0;i < 3;i++)
        printf("%d\n", *(arr1+i));
return 0;
}
```

I was getted question from other.
why this program print junk value.
i think. it have to linked to individual elements
like

`for(int i =0; i<3; i++) { arr1[i]=arr2[i] }`

but i dont know why, so tell me something..

Comment: `arr1 = arr2` in the function will just assign one pointer's address to the other; as those pointer arguments are just copies, nothing will actually be done. But your code has undefined behaviour, anyway, as neither array is initialized in `main`.

Comment: In your program above, you never initialized `arr1` to begin with.  So when you go to print the contents of `arr1`,  you are printing out garbage values.  Also, you aren't ever copying arr1 into arr2.  You are initializing arr2 with the values from 0 to 2.

Comment: @Adrian Mole thx! i understand!

Comment: A language's syntax doesn't tell you anything about what is actually happening underneath. a = b in different languages means entirely different things. Unless the book tells you that a = b will copy b into a, don't assume it.

Comment: @AdrianMole: Using an uninitialized array element does not have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a function definition such as `int func(int *arr1, int *arr2)`, the *parameters* of the function receive only *values* from the caller. When this function is called with `func(arr1, arr2)`, the *value* of `arr1` in `main` is passed as an argument to the function. Inside the function, the parameter `arr1` is a *copy* of this argument value.

Then, inside the function, the statement `arr1 = arr2;` only changes the value of this parameter. It has no effect on the value of `arr1` in `main`.

Consider this code in `main`:

```
int arr1[3];
int arr2[3];
int *p = arr1; // Set `p` to point to first element of `arr1`.
func(&p, arr2);
```

Then we change `func` to accept the address of a pointer instead of just a pointer:

```
int func(int **arr1, int *arr2)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        arr2[i] = i;
    *arr1 = arr2;
}
```

Then, when `func`, changes `*arr1`, it changes the object that its parameter `arr1` is pointing it. That object is the pointer `p` in `main`. Then, in `main`, you can print with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    printf("%d\n", p[i]);
```

Comment: good answer thanks. NB: the function should be void.

Comment: @EricPostpischil can you do &(&arr) and pass it around like you did if 'arr' is on the stack?

Comment: @tf3: No, because `&arr` is a value, not an object, so you cannot take its address with `&`. Once an array is defined, it has a fixed position and cannot be moved. (Its data could be copied to a new location, but that is a different thing.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Okay so this means that nothing at all happens to arr1, it's just that p points to the first element of arr2, right?

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't arr1=arr2 in function?

Because the C language specification (read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or newer) says so. In §6.5.16.1. See also [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c).

To summarize, you can assign scalar types (booleans, characters, enums, numbers or pointers), or `struct` or `union`s, but not arrays.

It seems that you are assigning a pointer passed by value as an argument. This has no effect on the caller and the pointer used as argument (actually the arrays in `main` decayed to pointers when passed to functions).

You could use the standard `memcpy` function to assign non-overlapping arrays.

Comment: In the `arr1 = arr2;` statement the OP is asking about, `arr1` is not an array. It is a pointer and can be assigned.

Answer (score -3):

You could do this
`for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {`
    `arr1[i] = arr2[i];`
    `break;`
`}`

Comment: what's the break there for?